# Does appending (merging) files together work with XCOPY?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-management, merge, xcopy

I want to merge multiple (text) files having the same prefix into a single file. This task is part of a whole batch (in VBScript) but due to performance expectations, I'm more likely to use a native command rather than programming a loop (opening each file, reading the whole content, then writing it down to the destination file) in VBScript.

Currently facing a problem with `COPY` which seems to require you to flush the StdOut buffer (because it outputs all files' names it copies) I was looking towards  `XCOPY` which has a lot more flags to configure its behavior and output (like `/Q` which *Suppresses the display of xcopy messages*).

Reading the doc:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491035(v=technet.10)

I came across this:

> Appending files
>
> To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (that is, by using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).

OK so I write: `xcopy "My file pattern whatsoever.*.tmp" "My destination file.tmp"`

Unfortunately it asks if `My destination file.tmp` is a file or a directory, to which I should answer with either `F` (for file) or `D` (for Directory). Note: it's language dependent (in my case - French - it's F or R).

I noticed this in the above doc:

> Specifying whether Destination is a file or directory
>
> If Destination does not contain an existing directory and does not end with a backslash (\), the following message appears:
>
> ```
> Does destination specify a file name 
> or directory name on the target 
> (F = file, D = directory)?
> ```
>
> Press F if you want the file or files to be copied to a file. Press D if you want the file or files to be copied to a directory.
>
> You can suppress this message by using the **/i** command-line option, which causes **xcopy** to assume that the destination is a directory if the source is more than one file or a directory.

Well, as this `/i` flag does not fit my need, I resort to a trick I read here & there, like (amongst answers): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134466

So I try this: `echo F|xcopy "My file pattern whatsoever.*.tmp" "My destination file.tmp"`

OK now, the first file is copied to the destination file, but for every following file, a question pops up about replacing the destination file (?!!).
By the way all are discarded because the `echo` command does not provided any input for them.

If I use this flag:

> **/y** : Suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

then I end up with a destination file containing only the content of the last file I want to merge (i.e. the last file matching the source pattern)!!!

I also tried checking if it works with only two files, e.g.: `xcopy "My file pattern whatsoever.0001.tmp"+"My file pattern whatsoever.0002.tmp" "My destination file.tmp" but I get an error:` File not found - My file pattern whatsoever.0001.tmp+My file pattern whatsoever.0002.tmp`

Same if I add spaces around the `+`; says `Invalid number of parameters`, probably because the file1+file2+file3 syntax doesn't work with long (including spaces) filenames, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651776/xcopy-returns-error-invalid-number-of-parameters-when-exclude-parameter-is-set

So what is wrong with what am I doing (or trying to)?

Comment: Note: I also tested the `*` trick at the end of *destination* to avoid the `/i` + `echo F|` like advised here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50451992 - and it works - but that doesn't help with the desired goal of merging **all** source files into 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some of the comments [on this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548431/getting-xcopy-to-concatenate-append), `xcopy` doesn't do the appending that its documentation says it does.

So you can use something like this instead.

```
type "My file pattern whatsoever.*.tmp" > "My destination file.tmp"
```

But `type` also outputs the filenames as it processes them, so you might run into the same problem that you are having with `copy`. To avoid that, you can redirect that unwanted output to NUL, like this:

```
type "My file pattern whatsoever.*.tmp" > "My destination file.tmp" 2>NUL
```

(Using `2>NUL`, because `type` displays the filenames on StdErr.)

And if you are doing that anyway, you can go back to using `copy`, like this:

```
copy "My file pattern whatsoever.*.tmp" "My destination file.tmp" >NUL
```

(Using `>NUL`, because `copy` displays the filenames on StdOut.)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I read this question earlier but as there wasn't any *clear* answer/explanation about why `xcopy` does not append/merge, I decided to ask myself. At the same time I tried to fix the `copy` issue and finally resorted to use this `> NUL` redirection.
BTW do you know if there is an advantage to use `type` over `copy` or that's basically the same?

Comment: Also I didn't pay attention to a link that was posted in the comments; in fact it's now 404 but with the help of Archive.org I could find what it was before, and the answer is explicit: **`XCOPY` does not merge files** due to (so-called) compatibility issues. See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548431/getting-xcopy-to-concatenate-append#comment100504860_25548431

Comment: As for advantages, `type` and `copy` are going to be the same for most situations. `Copy` can copy binary files or text files, while `type` will only work well with text files. And I've seen discussion about `type` being able to read locked files, while `copy` can not. But in my testing, neither one can read a locked file.

Comment: OK thanks again. For what I'm dealing with, I have to use the `/B` flag because some of my files are in UTF-8 thus the default copy mode doesn't handle encoding properly e.g. adding a SUB character at the end of the resulting file.